# retrieving users based on ID's with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

on clicking the button it sorts list of users by ID. and then It toggles the inactive to active text. 
When inactive sort by lowest ID’s first. When active sort by highest ID’s first.

how can i  code this problem using angularjs, can anyone tell me with an example if possible?

Comment: Show some example functionality. And show what you've tried.

Comment: <div ng-show="showMe">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in users | orderBy: '-id'" style="padding: 10px; text-align:left;">
        <img ng-src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/{{x.id}}?v=3" width="55" height="55" alt="user image"/>
        <a ng-href="https://github.com/{{x.login}}" style="float:left; padding:10px">view</a>
  {{x.login + ',' + x.id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>

Comment: <button ng-click="sortid()" style="color:blue;">sortBy GitID's</button>

Comment: var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.num=4;
    $scope.showMe=false;
    $scope.sortid=function(){
           $scope.showMe=!$scope.showMe;
    }

Comment: You should add this to your question and format it to help debug

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3AorderBy) you can use the `reverse` argument. Create a filter like this for descending mode:

```
filter:orderBy(array, expression[, reverse]);
```

If you wana have the array in ascending mode, no expression need to add(Default mode is ascending).
Regards.